# Instance respond to selector always return NO. But why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, skstorereviewcontroller

This statement is always false. Even on iOS 10.3 device.
I don't know why.

```
if ([NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreReviewController") instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(requestReview)]) {
    [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
}
```

PS If I remove if statement there is a review dialog on my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestReview` is a class method, not an instance method. Use `respondsToSelector` on the class.

```
if ([NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreReviewController") respondsToSelector:@selector(requestReview)]) {
    [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
}
```